# Is it possible to check if or not two existing GL contexts are sharing resources?

Tags: opengl, sharing

Seems like this question is rare. Just did some search online, but can not find an answer.

Comment: It's rare because, generally speaking, users don't have a pair of OpenGL contents unless they know where they came from. Since most users create their contexts or tell someone else to do it.

Comment: I guess my case is rare too. I own (compiled and linked) a bunch of shaders under a GL context (say A). Some of the shaders could be used by various other client GL contexts. Unfortunately, I do not know whether each client GL contexts is sharing with A or not, since wglShareLists() are called by client code. So, I do not know whether the client can re-use the compiled-linked shader.

Comment: If your client created context A, then your client must also have created context B. And therefore, your client should *tell you* if the two contexts are in a share group or not, since your client is the one who knows about it.

Comment: Yes, I understand it's doable to have clients tracking the sharing relationship. Unfortunately, it appears to be expensive because we have **many** other contexts than **B** there in client end, and in our legacy code, that tracking mechanism is not there.  I am wondering whether there is some OpenGL/wgl call can help. OpenGL must have that relationship tracked under the hood, right?

Comment: You could do something ugly, like create an object in one context, and then check if it exists in the other context. To be safe, check that it didn't exist before.

Answer (score 0):

Context sharing is an optional feature provided by GLX, WGL, EGL or similar. Strictly speaking **OpenGL** cannot query anything about shared context because it does not require any interfaces for shared contexts. The spec does mention certain behavior around shared contexts but that is about it.

For GLX, WGL and EGL there is no way of querying if contexts are sharing.

The comment by Reto suggests doing something in one context and see if it had effect in the other.

If you have control over your build envirnoment you could "hook" the operation used to share context, register the event, and then call the real operation.